# Sort by column and append counter using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, performance, running-count

I have a large data frame (>1m rows, 10+ cols) that I need to do the following to:

- Group by two of the columns (`A` & `B` in example)
- Sort within the grouping by another column (`C` in example)
- Append an incremental counter to another column, incrementing in the order of the sorted values of `C` (`E` in example)
- Leave other columns unedited (`D` in example)

I have got the following code working, which gives the correct results. However, it is very slow. Can anyone suggest some pandas magic to get improved performance?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(0)

A = list()
B = list()
C = list()
D = list()
E = list()

np_alphabet = np.array(list('ABCEEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'), dtype="|S1")
np_codes = np.random.choice(np_alphabet, [5, 10])
for a in np_codes:
    for b in range(2):
        for i in range(5):
            A.append(''.join(a))
            B.append('{}_{}'.format(b, A[-1]))
            C.append(np.random.rand())
            D.append(i)
            E.append(B[-1])

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': A,
    'B': B,
    'C': C,
    'D': D,
    'E': E
})
df.set_index(['A', 'B'], drop=False, inplace=True)
df.sort_index(inplace=True)

print(df)

grouped_sizes = df.groupby(level=[0, 1]).size()
num_indices = grouped_sizes.shape[0]
print_num = max(1, num_indices // 20)
for idx in grouped_sizes.index:
    if grouped_sizes[idx] > 1:
        tmp_df = df.loc[idx].sort_values('C', inplace=False)
        tmp_df['E'] = map(lambda x: '{}_{}'.format(*x), zip(range(1, tmp_df.size + 1), tmp_df['E']))
        df.loc[idx] = tmp_df
    else:
        df.loc[idx, 'E'] = '1_{}'.format(df.loc[idx, 'E'])

print(df)
```

which gives the following output

```
# before
                                  A             B         C  D             E
A          B                                                                
AXEJWVIZMZ 0_AXEJWVIZMZ  AXEJWVIZMZ  0_AXEJWVIZMZ  0.954914  0  0_AXEJWVIZMZ
           0_AXEJWVIZMZ  AXEJWVIZMZ  0_AXEJWVIZMZ  0.758615  1  0_AXEJWVIZMZ
           0_AXEJWVIZMZ  AXEJWVIZMZ  0_AXEJWVIZMZ  0.952573  2  0_AXEJWVIZMZ
           0_AXEJWVIZMZ  AXEJWVIZMZ  0_AXEJWVIZMZ  0.903142  3  0_AXEJWVIZMZ
           0_AXEJWVIZMZ  AXEJWVIZMZ  0_AXEJWVIZMZ  0.154262  4  0_AXEJWVIZMZ
           1_AXEJWVIZMZ  AXEJWVIZMZ  1_AXEJWVIZMZ  0.560586  0  1_AXEJWVIZMZ
           1_AXEJWVIZMZ  AXEJWVIZMZ  1_AXEJWVIZMZ  0.528869  1  1_AXEJWVIZMZ
           1_AXEJWVIZMZ  AXEJWVIZMZ  1_AXEJWVIZMZ  0.115331  2  1_AXEJWVIZMZ
           1_AXEJWVIZMZ  AXEJWVIZMZ  1_AXEJWVIZMZ  0.380718  3  1_AXEJWVIZMZ
           1_AXEJWVIZMZ  AXEJWVIZMZ  1_AXEJWVIZMZ  0.147092  4  1_AXEJWVIZMZ
BVBSPSACVA 0_BVBSPSACVA  BVBSPSACVA  0_BVBSPSACVA  0.824997  0  0_BVBSPSACVA
           0_BVBSPSACVA  BVBSPSACVA  0_BVBSPSACVA  0.264456  1  0_BVBSPSACVA
           0_BVBSPSACVA  BVBSPSACVA  0_BVBSPSACVA  0.282663  2  0_BVBSPSACVA
           0_BVBSPSACVA  BVBSPSACVA  0_BVBSPSACVA  0.678287  3  0_BVBSPSACVA
           0_BVBSPSACVA  BVBSPSACVA  0_BVBSPSACVA  0.409996  4  0_BVBSPSACVA
           1_BVBSPSACVA  BVBSPSACVA  1_BVBSPSACVA  0.149984  0  1_BVBSPSACVA
           1_BVBSPSACVA  BVBSPSACVA  1_BVBSPSACVA  0.711210  1  1_BVBSPSACVA
           1_BVBSPSACVA  BVBSPSACVA  1_BVBSPSACVA  0.840399  2  1_BVBSPSACVA
           1_BVBSPSACVA  BVBSPSACVA  1_BVBSPSACVA  0.804939  3  1_BVBSPSACVA
           1_BVBSPSACVA  BVBSPSACVA  1_BVBSPSACVA  0.290150  4  1_BVBSPSACVA
FHNMIRQRSP 0_FHNMIRQRSP  FHNMIRQRSP  0_FHNMIRQRSP  0.119058  0  0_FHNMIRQRSP
           0_FHNMIRQRSP  FHNMIRQRSP  0_FHNMIRQRSP  0.021955  1  0_FHNMIRQRSP
           0_FHNMIRQRSP  FHNMIRQRSP  0_FHNMIRQRSP  0.299527  2  0_FHNMIRQRSP
           0_FHNMIRQRSP  FHNMIRQRSP  0_FHNMIRQRSP  0.449371  3  0_FHNMIRQRSP
           0_FHNMIRQRSP  FHNMIRQRSP  0_FHNMIRQRSP  0.179845  4  0_FHNMIRQRSP
           1_FHNMIRQRSP  FHNMIRQRSP  1_FHNMIRQRSP  0.075765  0  1_FHNMIRQRSP
           1_FHNMIRQRSP  FHNMIRQRSP  1_FHNMIRQRSP  0.413373  1  1_FHNMIRQRSP
           1_FHNMIRQRSP  FHNMIRQRSP  1_FHNMIRQRSP  0.835250  2  1_FHNMIRQRSP
           1_FHNMIRQRSP  FHNMIRQRSP  1_FHNMIRQRSP  0.371984  3  1_FHNMIRQRSP
           1_FHNMIRQRSP  FHNMIRQRSP  1_FHNMIRQRSP  0.265494  4  1_FHNMIRQRSP
TJSECSLWFT 0_TJSECSLWFT  TJSECSLWFT  0_TJSECSLWFT  0.804553  0  0_TJSECSLWFT
           0_TJSECSLWFT  TJSECSLWFT  0_TJSECSLWFT  0.376646  1  0_TJSECSLWFT
           0_TJSECSLWFT  TJSECSLWFT  0_TJSECSLWFT  0.904908  2  0_TJSECSLWFT
           0_TJSECSLWFT  TJSECSLWFT  0_TJSECSLWFT  0.274501  3  0_TJSECSLWFT
           0_TJSECSLWFT  TJSECSLWFT  0_TJSECSLWFT  0.820866  4  0_TJSECSLWFT
           1_TJSECSLWFT  TJSECSLWFT  1_TJSECSLWFT  0.886687  0  1_TJSECSLWFT
           1_TJSECSLWFT  TJSECSLWFT  1_TJSECSLWFT  0.198887  1  1_TJSECSLWFT
           1_TJSECSLWFT  TJSECSLWFT  1_TJSECSLWFT  0.857795  2  1_TJSECSLWFT
           1_TJSECSLWFT  TJSECSLWFT  1_TJSECSLWFT  0.326926  3  1_TJSECSLWFT
           1_TJSECSLWFT  TJSECSLWFT  1_TJSECSLWFT  0.116743  4  1_TJSECSLWFT
WXEKPQSLQK 0_WXEKPQSLQK  WXEKPQSLQK  0_WXEKPQSLQK  0.249891  0  0_WXEKPQSLQK
           0_WXEKPQSLQK  WXEKPQSLQK  0_WXEKPQSLQK  0.945414  1  0_WXEKPQSLQK
           0_WXEKPQSLQK  WXEKPQSLQK  0_WXEKPQSLQK  0.235062  2  0_WXEKPQSLQK
           0_WXEKPQSLQK  WXEKPQSLQK  0_WXEKPQSLQK  0.082703  3  0_WXEKPQSLQK
           0_WXEKPQSLQK  WXEKPQSLQK  0_WXEKPQSLQK  0.894169  4  0_WXEKPQSLQK
           1_WXEKPQSLQK  WXEKPQSLQK  1_WXEKPQSLQK  0.595575  0  1_WXEKPQSLQK
           1_WXEKPQSLQK  WXEKPQSLQK  1_WXEKPQSLQK  0.769144  1  1_WXEKPQSLQK
           1_WXEKPQSLQK  WXEKPQSLQK  1_WXEKPQSLQK  0.917691  2  1_WXEKPQSLQK
           1_WXEKPQSLQK  WXEKPQSLQK  1_WXEKPQSLQK  0.567448  3  1_WXEKPQSLQK
           1_WXEKPQSLQK  WXEKPQSLQK  1_WXEKPQSLQK  0.832299  4  1_WXEKPQSLQK
```

and

```
# after
                                  A             B         C  D               E
A          B                                                                  
AXEJWVIZMZ 0_AXEJWVIZMZ  AXEJWVIZMZ  0_AXEJWVIZMZ  0.154262  4  1_0_AXEJWVIZMZ
           0_AXEJWVIZMZ  AXEJWVIZMZ  0_AXEJWVIZMZ  0.758615  1  2_0_AXEJWVIZMZ
           0_AXEJWVIZMZ  AXEJWVIZMZ  0_AXEJWVIZMZ  0.903142  3  3_0_AXEJWVIZMZ
           0_AXEJWVIZMZ  AXEJWVIZMZ  0_AXEJWVIZMZ  0.952573  2  4_0_AXEJWVIZMZ
           0_AXEJWVIZMZ  AXEJWVIZMZ  0_AXEJWVIZMZ  0.954914  0  5_0_AXEJWVIZMZ
           1_AXEJWVIZMZ  AXEJWVIZMZ  1_AXEJWVIZMZ  0.115331  2  1_1_AXEJWVIZMZ
           1_AXEJWVIZMZ  AXEJWVIZMZ  1_AXEJWVIZMZ  0.147092  4  2_1_AXEJWVIZMZ
           1_AXEJWVIZMZ  AXEJWVIZMZ  1_AXEJWVIZMZ  0.380718  3  3_1_AXEJWVIZMZ
           1_AXEJWVIZMZ  AXEJWVIZMZ  1_AXEJWVIZMZ  0.528869  1  4_1_AXEJWVIZMZ
           1_AXEJWVIZMZ  AXEJWVIZMZ  1_AXEJWVIZMZ  0.560586  0  5_1_AXEJWVIZMZ
BVBSPSACVA 0_BVBSPSACVA  BVBSPSACVA  0_BVBSPSACVA  0.264456  1  1_0_BVBSPSACVA
           0_BVBSPSACVA  BVBSPSACVA  0_BVBSPSACVA  0.282663  2  2_0_BVBSPSACVA
           0_BVBSPSACVA  BVBSPSACVA  0_BVBSPSACVA  0.409996  4  3_0_BVBSPSACVA
           0_BVBSPSACVA  BVBSPSACVA  0_BVBSPSACVA  0.678287  3  4_0_BVBSPSACVA
           0_BVBSPSACVA  BVBSPSACVA  0_BVBSPSACVA  0.824997  0  5_0_BVBSPSACVA
           1_BVBSPSACVA  BVBSPSACVA  1_BVBSPSACVA  0.149984  0  1_1_BVBSPSACVA
           1_BVBSPSACVA  BVBSPSACVA  1_BVBSPSACVA  0.290150  4  2_1_BVBSPSACVA
           1_BVBSPSACVA  BVBSPSACVA  1_BVBSPSACVA  0.711210  1  3_1_BVBSPSACVA
           1_BVBSPSACVA  BVBSPSACVA  1_BVBSPSACVA  0.804939  3  4_1_BVBSPSACVA
           1_BVBSPSACVA  BVBSPSACVA  1_BVBSPSACVA  0.840399  2  5_1_BVBSPSACVA
FHNMIRQRSP 0_FHNMIRQRSP  FHNMIRQRSP  0_FHNMIRQRSP  0.021955  1  1_0_FHNMIRQRSP
           0_FHNMIRQRSP  FHNMIRQRSP  0_FHNMIRQRSP  0.119058  0  2_0_FHNMIRQRSP
           0_FHNMIRQRSP  FHNMIRQRSP  0_FHNMIRQRSP  0.179845  4  3_0_FHNMIRQRSP
           0_FHNMIRQRSP  FHNMIRQRSP  0_FHNMIRQRSP  0.299527  2  4_0_FHNMIRQRSP
           0_FHNMIRQRSP  FHNMIRQRSP  0_FHNMIRQRSP  0.449371  3  5_0_FHNMIRQRSP
           1_FHNMIRQRSP  FHNMIRQRSP  1_FHNMIRQRSP  0.075765  0  1_1_FHNMIRQRSP
           1_FHNMIRQRSP  FHNMIRQRSP  1_FHNMIRQRSP  0.265494  4  2_1_FHNMIRQRSP
           1_FHNMIRQRSP  FHNMIRQRSP  1_FHNMIRQRSP  0.371984  3  3_1_FHNMIRQRSP
           1_FHNMIRQRSP  FHNMIRQRSP  1_FHNMIRQRSP  0.413373  1  4_1_FHNMIRQRSP
           1_FHNMIRQRSP  FHNMIRQRSP  1_FHNMIRQRSP  0.835250  2  5_1_FHNMIRQRSP
TJSECSLWFT 0_TJSECSLWFT  TJSECSLWFT  0_TJSECSLWFT  0.274501  3  1_0_TJSECSLWFT
           0_TJSECSLWFT  TJSECSLWFT  0_TJSECSLWFT  0.376646  1  2_0_TJSECSLWFT
           0_TJSECSLWFT  TJSECSLWFT  0_TJSECSLWFT  0.804553  0  3_0_TJSECSLWFT
           0_TJSECSLWFT  TJSECSLWFT  0_TJSECSLWFT  0.820866  4  4_0_TJSECSLWFT
           0_TJSECSLWFT  TJSECSLWFT  0_TJSECSLWFT  0.904908  2  5_0_TJSECSLWFT
           1_TJSECSLWFT  TJSECSLWFT  1_TJSECSLWFT  0.116743  4  1_1_TJSECSLWFT
           1_TJSECSLWFT  TJSECSLWFT  1_TJSECSLWFT  0.198887  1  2_1_TJSECSLWFT
           1_TJSECSLWFT  TJSECSLWFT  1_TJSECSLWFT  0.326926  3  3_1_TJSECSLWFT
           1_TJSECSLWFT  TJSECSLWFT  1_TJSECSLWFT  0.857795  2  4_1_TJSECSLWFT
           1_TJSECSLWFT  TJSECSLWFT  1_TJSECSLWFT  0.886687  0  5_1_TJSECSLWFT
WXEKPQSLQK 0_WXEKPQSLQK  WXEKPQSLQK  0_WXEKPQSLQK  0.082703  3  1_0_WXEKPQSLQK
           0_WXEKPQSLQK  WXEKPQSLQK  0_WXEKPQSLQK  0.235062  2  2_0_WXEKPQSLQK
           0_WXEKPQSLQK  WXEKPQSLQK  0_WXEKPQSLQK  0.249891  0  3_0_WXEKPQSLQK
           0_WXEKPQSLQK  WXEKPQSLQK  0_WXEKPQSLQK  0.894169  4  4_0_WXEKPQSLQK
           0_WXEKPQSLQK  WXEKPQSLQK  0_WXEKPQSLQK  0.945414  1  5_0_WXEKPQSLQK
           1_WXEKPQSLQK  WXEKPQSLQK  1_WXEKPQSLQK  0.567448  3  1_1_WXEKPQSLQK
           1_WXEKPQSLQK  WXEKPQSLQK  1_WXEKPQSLQK  0.595575  0  2_1_WXEKPQSLQK
           1_WXEKPQSLQK  WXEKPQSLQK  1_WXEKPQSLQK  0.769144  1  3_1_WXEKPQSLQK
           1_WXEKPQSLQK  WXEKPQSLQK  1_WXEKPQSLQK  0.832299  4  4_1_WXEKPQSLQK
           1_WXEKPQSLQK  WXEKPQSLQK  1_WXEKPQSLQK  0.917691  2  5_1_WXEKPQSLQK
```

## EDIT: A new suggestion, timing, and testing of other suggested answers

```
from __future__ import print_function, division
from timeit import Timer
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


def create_df():
    np.random.seed(0)
    A = list()
    B = list()
    C = list()
    D = list()
    E = list()

    np_alphabet = np.array(list('ABCEEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'), dtype="|S1")
    np_codes = np.random.choice(np_alphabet, [100, 10])
    for a in np_codes:
        for b in range(2):
            for i in range(5):
                A.append(''.join(a))
                B.append('{}_{}'.format(b, A[-1]))
                C.append(np.random.rand())
                D.append(i)
                E.append(B[-1])

    df = pd.DataFrame({
        'A': A,
        'B': B,
        'C': C,
        'D': D,
        'E': E
    })
    return df.copy()


def method1(df):
    df.set_index(['A', 'B'], drop=False, inplace=True)
    df.sort_index(inplace=True)
    grouped_sizes = df.groupby(level=[0, 1]).size()
    for idx in grouped_sizes.index:
        if grouped_sizes[idx] > 1:
            tmp_df = df.loc[idx].sort_values('C', inplace=False)
            tmp_df['E'] = map(lambda x: '{}_{}'.format(*x), zip(range(1, tmp_df.size + 1), tmp_df['E']))
            df.loc[idx] = tmp_df
        else:
            df.loc[idx, 'E'] = '1_{}'.format(df.loc[idx, 'E'])
    return df


def method1a(df):
    df.set_index(['A', 'B'], drop=False, inplace=True)
    df.sort_values(['A', 'B', 'C'], inplace=True)
    grouped_sizes = df.groupby(level=[0, 1]).size()
    for idx in grouped_sizes.index:
        if grouped_sizes[idx] > 1:
            df.loc[idx, 'E'] = map(lambda x: '{}_{}'.format(*x), zip(range(1, grouped_sizes[idx] + 1), df.loc[idx, 'E']))
        else:
            df.loc[idx, 'E'] = '1_{}'.format(df.loc[idx, 'E'])
    return df


def method2(df):
    df.set_index(['A', 'B'], drop=False, inplace=True)
    df['F'] = 0
    df.sort_values(['A', 'B', 'C'], inplace=True)
    grouped_sizes = df.groupby(level=[0, 1]).size()
    for idx in grouped_sizes.index:
        if grouped_sizes[idx] > 1:
            df.loc[idx, 'F'] = range(1, grouped_sizes[idx] + 1)
        else:
            df.loc[idx, 'F'] = 1
    df['E'] = df['F'].map(str) + '_' + df['E']
    df.drop('F', axis=1, inplace=True)
    return df


def method3(df):
    df.set_index(['A', 'B'], drop=False, inplace=True)
    df['F'] = 0
    df.sort_values(['A', 'B', 'C'], inplace=True)
    grouped_sizes = df.groupby(level=[0, 1]).size()
    for idx in grouped_sizes.index:
        if grouped_sizes[idx] > 1:
            df.loc[idx, 'F'] = map(str, range(1, grouped_sizes[idx] + 1))
        else:
            df.loc[idx, 'F'] = '1'
    df['E'] = df['F'] + '_' + df['E']
    df.drop('F', axis=1, inplace=True)
    return df


def method4(df):
    prefixes = df.groupby(['A', 'B']).C.apply(pd.Series.argsort).add(1).astype(str)
    df['E'] = prefixes + '_' + df.E
    return df


def method5(df):
    df.set_index(['A', 'B'], drop=False, inplace=True)
    df.sort_values(['A', 'B', 'C'], inplace=True)
    df['E'] = df.groupby(level=[0, 1]).cumcount().add(1).astype(str) + '_' + df['E']
    return df


def assert_success(df):
    row = df[(df['A'] == 'AEVFGIURPE') & (df['B'] == '0_AEVFGIURPE') & (df['D'] == 2)].iloc[0]
    if not np.allclose(row['C'], 0.381397) or row['E'] != '3_0_AEVFGIURPE':
        print('A: method{}() failed: {} != 0.871083 or {} != 5_1_XOYRFZNIJU'.format(func, row['C'], row['E']))
        return
    row = df[(df['A'] == 'XOYRFZNIJU') & (df['B'] == '1_XOYRFZNIJU') & (df['D'] == 1)].iloc[0]
    if not np.allclose(row['C'], 0.871083) or row['E'] != '5_1_XOYRFZNIJU':
        print('B: method{}() failed: {} != 0.871083 or {} != 5_1_XOYRFZNIJU'.format(func, row['C'], row['E']))
        return


functions = list()
functions.append('1')
functions.append('1a')
functions.append('2')
functions.append('3')
functions.append('4')
functions.append('5')
for func in functions:
    print('method{}'.format(func),
          Timer(setup='from __main__ import create_df, assert_success, method{} as func'.format(func),
                stmt='df = create_df(); df = func(df); assert_success(df)').repeat(number=10))
```

Which gives the following results:

```
method1 [6.581194877624512, 6.625822067260742, 6.722187042236328]
method1a [1.9003210067749023, 1.9387969970703125, 1.9142169952392578]
method2 [0.9547598361968994, 0.9532740116119385, 0.9760739803314209]
method3 [1.0121638774871826, 1.0000989437103271, 0.9709858894348145]
B: method4() failed: 0.871082572438 != 0.871083 or 1_1_XOYRFZNIJU != 5_1_XOYRFZNIJU
B: method4() failed: 0.871082572438 != 0.871083 or 1_1_XOYRFZNIJU != 5_1_XOYRFZNIJU
B: method4() failed: 0.871082572438 != 0.871083 or 1_1_XOYRFZNIJU != 5_1_XOYRFZNIJU
B: method4() failed: 0.871082572438 != 0.871083 or 1_1_XOYRFZNIJU != 5_1_XOYRFZNIJU
B: method4() failed: 0.871082572438 != 0.871083 or 1_1_XOYRFZNIJU != 5_1_XOYRFZNIJU
B: method4() failed: 0.871082572438 != 0.871083 or 1_1_XOYRFZNIJU != 5_1_XOYRFZNIJU
B: method4() failed: 0.871082572438 != 0.871083 or 1_1_XOYRFZNIJU != 5_1_XOYRFZNIJU
B: method4() failed: 0.871082572438 != 0.871083 or 1_1_XOYRFZNIJU != 5_1_XOYRFZNIJU
B: method4() failed: 0.871082572438 != 0.871083 or 1_1_XOYRFZNIJU != 5_1_XOYRFZNIJU
B: method4() failed: 0.871082572438 != 0.871083 or 1_1_XOYRFZNIJU != 5_1_XOYRFZNIJU
B: method4() failed: 0.871082572438 != 0.871083 or 1_1_XOYRFZNIJU != 5_1_XOYRFZNIJU
B: method4() failed: 0.871082572438 != 0.871083 or 1_1_XOYRFZNIJU != 5_1_XOYRFZNIJU
B: method4() failed: 0.871082572438 != 0.871083 or 1_1_XOYRFZNIJU != 5_1_XOYRFZNIJU
B: method4() failed: 0.871082572438 != 0.871083 or 1_1_XOYRFZNIJU != 5_1_XOYRFZNIJU
B: method4() failed: 0.871082572438 != 0.871083 or 1_1_XOYRFZNIJU != 5_1_XOYRFZNIJU
B: method4() failed: 0.871082572438 != 0.871083 or 1_1_XOYRFZNIJU != 5_1_XOYRFZNIJU
B: method4() failed: 0.871082572438 != 0.871083 or 1_1_XOYRFZNIJU != 5_1_XOYRFZNIJU
B: method4() failed: 0.871082572438 != 0.871083 or 1_1_XOYRFZNIJU != 5_1_XOYRFZNIJU
B: method4() failed: 0.871082572438 != 0.871083 or 1_1_XOYRFZNIJU != 5_1_XOYRFZNIJU
B: method4() failed: 0.871082572438 != 0.871083 or 1_1_XOYRFZNIJU != 5_1_XOYRFZNIJU
B: method4() failed: 0.871082572438 != 0.871083 or 1_1_XOYRFZNIJU != 5_1_XOYRFZNIJU
B: method4() failed: 0.871082572438 != 0.871083 or 1_1_XOYRFZNIJU != 5_1_XOYRFZNIJU
B: method4() failed: 0.871082572438 != 0.871083 or 1_1_XOYRFZNIJU != 5_1_XOYRFZNIJU
B: method4() failed: 0.871082572438 != 0.871083 or 1_1_XOYRFZNIJU != 5_1_XOYRFZNIJU
B: method4() failed: 0.871082572438 != 0.871083 or 1_1_XOYRFZNIJU != 5_1_XOYRFZNIJU
B: method4() failed: 0.871082572438 != 0.871083 or 1_1_XOYRFZNIJU != 5_1_XOYRFZNIJU
B: method4() failed: 0.871082572438 != 0.871083 or 1_1_XOYRFZNIJU != 5_1_XOYRFZNIJU
B: method4() failed: 0.871082572438 != 0.871083 or 1_1_XOYRFZNIJU != 5_1_XOYRFZNIJU
B: method4() failed: 0.871082572438 != 0.871083 or 1_1_XOYRFZNIJU != 5_1_XOYRFZNIJU
B: method4() failed: 0.871082572438 != 0.871083 or 1_1_XOYRFZNIJU != 5_1_XOYRFZNIJU
method4 [0.3202958106994629, 0.3348369598388672, 0.33800482749938965]
method5 [0.11518096923828125, 0.10490703582763672, 0.09626197814941406]
```

Comment: My answer below times the suggested answers...

Comment: @piRSquared That is a pandas version error it would seem -- original code worked on OSX, but I just confirmed it caused the error that you mentioned in an ubuntu VM I am running. I have updated the code to work on both. The timings are unchanged, and your suggested answer unfortunately doesn't give the correct result.

Comment: @piRSquared Have moved my answer into editing the question. Also note the testing function that exists exactly to your point of *not* blindly using other peoples code, rather selecting the best response based on data.

Comment: No worries, thanks for the suggestion anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) first, then [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) + [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for counter, then add `1` and convert to `str`:

```
df.sort_values(['A', 'B', 'C'], inplace=True)
df['E'] = df.groupby(level=['A','B']).cumcount().add(1).astype(str) + '_' + df['E']
print(df)
                                  A             B         C  D               E
A          B                                                                  
MPVAEEHJTV 0_MPVAEEHJTV  MPVAEEHJTV  0_MPVAEEHJTV  0.264556  3  1_0_MPVAEEHJTV
           0_MPVAEEHJTV  MPVAEEHJTV  0_MPVAEEHJTV  0.414662  2  2_0_MPVAEEHJTV
           0_MPVAEEHJTV  MPVAEEHJTV  0_MPVAEEHJTV  0.521848  1  3_0_MPVAEEHJTV
           0_MPVAEEHJTV  MPVAEEHJTV  0_MPVAEEHJTV  0.774234  4  4_0_MPVAEEHJTV
           0_MPVAEEHJTV  MPVAEEHJTV  0_MPVAEEHJTV  0.944669  0  5_0_MPVAEEHJTV
           1_MPVAEEHJTV  MPVAEEHJTV  1_MPVAEEHJTV  0.018790  2  1_1_MPVAEEHJTV
           1_MPVAEEHJTV  MPVAEEHJTV  1_MPVAEEHJTV  0.456150  0  2_1_MPVAEEHJTV
           1_MPVAEEHJTV  MPVAEEHJTV  1_MPVAEEHJTV  0.568434  1  3_1_MPVAEEHJTV
           1_MPVAEEHJTV  MPVAEEHJTV  1_MPVAEEHJTV  0.612096  4  4_1_MPVAEEHJTV
           1_MPVAEEHJTV  MPVAEEHJTV  1_MPVAEEHJTV  0.617635  3  5_1_MPVAEEHJTV
RTTTOHABJZ 0_RTTTOHABJZ  RTTTOHABJZ  0_RTTTOHABJZ  0.096098  2  1_0_RTTTOHABJZ
           0_RTTTOHABJZ  RTTTOHABJZ  0_RTTTOHABJZ  0.097101  0  2_0_RTTTOHABJZ
           0_RTTTOHABJZ  RTTTOHABJZ  0_RTTTOHABJZ  0.468651  4  3_0_RTTTOHABJZ
           0_RTTTOHABJZ  RTTTOHABJZ  0_RTTTOHABJZ  0.837945  1  4_0_RTTTOHABJZ
           0_RTTTOHABJZ  RTTTOHABJZ  0_RTTTOHABJZ  0.976459  3  5_0_RTTTOHABJZ
           1_RTTTOHABJZ  RTTTOHABJZ  1_RTTTOHABJZ  0.039188  3  1_1_RTTTOHABJZ
...
...
```

EDIT:

It seems like bug if dont define `levels` by columns only if column names are same as index names:

```
df['E'] = df.groupby(['A','B']).cumcount().add(1).astype(str) + '_' + df['E']
```

> FutureWarning: 'A' is both a column name and an index level.
>   Defaulting to column but this will raise an ambiguity error in a future version
>         df['E'] = df.groupby(column=['A','B']).cumcount().add(1).astype(str) + '_' + df['E']
>
> FutureWarning: 'B' is both a column name and an index level.
>   Defaulting to column but this will raise an ambiguity error in a future version
>     df['E'] = df.groupby(column=['A','B']).cumcount().add(1).astype(str) + '_' + df['E']

One possible solution is [`rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) if necessary groupby by columns names (or rename columns which same names as index names):

```
df.sort_values(['A', 'B', 'C'], inplace=True)
df = df.rename_axis(('A_lev','B_lev'))
df['E'] = df.groupby(['A','B']).cumcount().add(1).astype(str) + '_' + df['E']
print(df)
                                  A             B         C  D               E
A_lev      B_lev                                                              
MPVAEEHJTV 0_MPVAEEHJTV  MPVAEEHJTV  0_MPVAEEHJTV  0.264556  3  1_0_MPVAEEHJTV
           0_MPVAEEHJTV  MPVAEEHJTV  0_MPVAEEHJTV  0.414662  2  2_0_MPVAEEHJTV
           0_MPVAEEHJTV  MPVAEEHJTV  0_MPVAEEHJTV  0.521848  1  3_0_MPVAEEHJTV
           0_MPVAEEHJTV  MPVAEEHJTV  0_MPVAEEHJTV  0.774234  4  4_0_MPVAEEHJTV
           0_MPVAEEHJTV  MPVAEEHJTV  0_MPVAEEHJTV  0.944669  0  5_0_MPVAEEHJTV
           1_MPVAEEHJTV  MPVAEEHJTV  1_MPVAEEHJTV  0.018790  2  1_1_MPVAEEHJTV
           1_MPVAEEHJTV  MPVAEEHJTV  1_MPVAEEHJTV  0.456150  0  2_1_MPVAEEHJTV
           1_MPVAEEHJTV  MPVAEEHJTV  1_MPVAEEHJTV  0.568434  1  3_1_MPVAEEHJTV
           1_MPVAEEHJTV  MPVAEEHJTV  1_MPVAEEHJTV  0.612096  4  4_1_MPVAEEHJTV
           1_MPVAEEHJTV  MPVAEEHJTV  1_MPVAEEHJTV  0.617635  3  5_1_MPVAEEHJTV
RTTTOHABJZ 0_RTTTOHABJZ  RTTTOHABJZ  0_RTTTOHABJZ  0.096098  2  1_0_RTTTOHABJZ
           0_RTTTOHABJZ  RTTTOHABJZ  0_RTTTOHABJZ  0.097101  0  2_0_RTTTOHABJZ
           0_RTTTOHABJZ  RTTTOHABJZ  0_RTTTOHABJZ  0.468651  4  3_0_RTTTOHABJZ
           0_RTTTOHABJZ  RTTTOHABJZ  0_RTTTOHABJZ  0.837945  1  4_0_RTTTOHABJZ
           0_RTTTOHABJZ  RTTTOHABJZ  0_RTTTOHABJZ  0.976459  3  5_0_RTTTOHABJZ
           1_RTTTOHABJZ  RTTTOHABJZ  1_RTTTOHABJZ  0.039188  3  1_1_RTTTOHABJZ
           1_RTTTOHABJZ  RTTTOHABJZ  1_RTTTOHABJZ  0.282807  4  2_1_RTTTOHABJZ
           1_RTTTOHABJZ  RTTTOHABJZ  1_RTTTOHABJZ  0.604846  1  3_1_RTTTOHABJZ
           1_RTTTOHABJZ  RTTTOHABJZ  1_RTTTOHABJZ  0.739264  2  4_1_RTTTOHABJZ
           1_RTTTOHABJZ  RTTTOHABJZ  1_RTTTOHABJZ  0.976761  0  5_1_RTTTOHABJZ
...
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Sort your dataframe first, then use the `.groupby()` method with a `.cumcount()`:

```
df.sort_values(['A','B','C'], inplace = True)
df['D'] = df.groupby(['A','B']).cumcount()
```

If you want to sort it the other way, supply an `ascending` parameter to `.sort_values()`: `ascending = [True,True,False]`. You also actually don't need to sort by A and B if you want to retain the original ordering of the data (they will still be 'ranked' correctly).

A general remark: if you find yourself using a for loop in pandas to iterate over data, chances are that you can speed up your code substantially by making use of pandas' vectorization.